# How can Javascript access data sent from Python Flask's render_template() function?

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

Problem: I am trying to access data I send (when the user navigates to the landing page of the site) from Javascript code so I can display it when the document is ready. This data is a dataframe.

Python Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
@app.route("/",methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def homeLanding():
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['ab1234','12:34'],['cd1234','12:36'],['ae54548','12:55'],['df59894','12:56']])
    df2 = df.to_json(orient='records')
    return render_template("index.html",someResponse=df2,namespace='/test')
```

Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Convert response dataframe to variable
    console.log(someResponse);
    var x = JSON.parse(someResponse);
    //print response dataframe
    console.log(x);
    //populate table with response dataframe.
    $('#table1').DataTable({
        "destroy":true,
        "searching": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "paging": false,
        "bordering":true,
        data: x,
        columns: [
        {"title": 'ID'},
        {"title": 'Time'},
        ]
    });
});
```

html Script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="static/js/application.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/application.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container-wrapper" margin="auto">
                <table id="table1" class="display"></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Current Status: I have been trying several ways of passing the dataframe to render_template() but the dataframe does not seem to get sent over to the client's Javascript code or I do not know how to properly access the data from Javascript response. The dataframe does not print to the console and it does not populate table1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First thing to do is work out whether or not the dataframe is being serialized to the client. Look at the network trace on the client. If it *is* serialized then you can focus on the client-side JavaScript; if not, then focus on the server-side Flask app.

Comment: Thanks. It does not seem that it is serialized/sent to the client. But what is the proper way of sending the dataframe using render_template?

Comment: should not it be `"{{ someResponse }}"` in place of someResponse in javascript

Comment: Thanks. I get an error: "expected property name, got '{'"

Comment: Is the JavaScript code that you've shown actually in index.html? If not, then the template engine won't inject the dataframe. If it *is* inside index.html then the way you refer to injected values is, for example, `{{ user }}` (if you passed a `user` parameter to render_template).

Comment: No. The Javascript code is in its own file.

Comment: add this js code inside your html page then it will work

Comment: @Tiger FYI when responding to someone in comments, please mention them by name in your comment, as I have done here with your name, otherwise they may not be notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`someResponse` is a Python object, and is rendered onto the html/js not as a JS object, but essentially a string (inspect your code through the browser to see what I mean).

In this case, your template code should be:

```
console.log("{{ someResponse }}");
var x = JSON.parse("{{ someResponse }}");
...
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I get it to display in a table JQuery table element on index.html if  index.html script is as follows:<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
.....all script references have been omitted for commenting purpose
        
.....all style references have been omitted for commenting purpose
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container-wrapper" margin="auto">
                <table id="table1" class="display" ></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: You can keep your JS file separate, just put the `var x` declaration inside a `<script>` tag on the html page. Just make sure it's before the reference to the table js file.

Answer (score 0):

Write your js code inside your html file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Convert response dataframe to variable
    console.log("{{ someResponse }}");
    var x = JSON.parse("{{ someResponse }}");
    //print response dataframe
    console.log(x);
    .......

</script>
```

You won't be able to pass this variable from backend to javascript file.

Comment: Does that mean I have to take out the other Javascript file?